# how to make a login disappear when user is logged in using php

Tags: php

I have a login at the top of each page on my site, when the user is logged in I want the login form to disappear, how do I do this in php? I'm not quite sure and have been looking a lot online but can't find how to do it.

Here is my code

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($count == 1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    }else {
        echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
    }
}
?>
<div id = "login_details">
<?php      
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    echo "Hello " . $username . " ". "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}
?>
<div id="login">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" >Username:</label>
        <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" size="10" placeholder="Username"/>
        <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Password:</label>
        <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" size="10" placeholder="Password" /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
    </form>
    <p>Not a member? <a href ="register.php">Register</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: when user is login you have created a session with some value. put a check if that value existing session then button will show otherwise not.

Comment: `if ($user_not_logged_in) { show login stuff }`. And... lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com). Your login system is utterly useless, since anyone with a modicum of sql knowledge can bypass it

Comment: `return;` - `exit;` - `die();` - [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) - too many ways. question is unclear. Oh, this isn't for a LIVE site, correct? Say: *correct*.

Comment: sorry thought i had copied all my code, its all there now

Comment: Fred this is for a uni project which I am doing

Comment: why don't you just redirect them to another page using a header and using `isset()` on that page as well? a lot easier. using your present code, you'd need to place your entire form inside an echo with a conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="login <?if($_SESSION['username'] != ''){echo "hidden";}?>">
  /* <our login form here */ 
</div>
```

add a class to the div that shows the login-field and than set that class up do be hidden via css:

```
.hidden{display:none;}
```

Thus you hide the div with your login-form when the user is loged in.

Answer (score 0):

move the rendering of your login box into the else of the following:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
```

then it will render the login box if the user is not logged in, and render the greeting if they are.

so the following didn't work:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  echo "Hello " . $username . " ". "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}
else{
//script to render login box e.g.
$login = <<<LOGIN
<form id="login" name="login" method="post" action="#">
<label for="uName">User Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="uName" id="uName" />
<label for="pwd">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" />
</form>
LOGIN;

echo $login;
```

please update your question to include what you have tried and what the results were.